# Hibernate: group by very slow

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have performance problems with the group by feature in Hibernate. Consider this 2 classes:

```
public class Project
{
...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    private User user;
...
}

public class User
{
...
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
...
}
```

Now I try to get a list of all Users assigned to the project. But this query is uselessly slow (more than 100'000 project entries, a lot of joins):

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
String SQL="SELECT user.id as id, user.name as name FROM Project p GROUP BY p.user.id";
Query q = session.createQuery(SQL);
q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List<Object> list = q.list();
session.close();
```

I try to change the query this way, but this is not working either because the variable user is an Object (but this would work as a native SQL query):

```
SELECT id, name FROM User WHERE id IN(SELECT user FROM Project GROUP BY user)
```

Any other ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an **[index](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Index.html)** from the foreign key column.

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "project")
@Table(appliesTo = "project" ,indexes = @Index(columnNames = "user", name = "user_index"))
@Entity
public class Project
{
 ..
```

**Update**

`columnNames` has been depricated. Use `columnList` instead.

```
@Index(columnList = "user", name = "user_index")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Adding an Index was the solution. columnNames seems to be deprecated. Had to use columnList instead.

Comment: @centaurio : Glad it helped. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this has to do with Hibernate being slow. Most probably the SQL query is slow if run directly on the database as well.

One good practice is to create indices whenever you have a foreign key in your table. In your case create an index for `user_id` on your `project` table and run the query once more.

Comment: Thank you! Adding an Index was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all users assigned to the project you don't need `group by`. Do something like this

```
select user from Project project inner join project.user user where project.id = :projectId
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually i want a list of all users assigned to any project, not just one. But this was my mistake, sorry.